# How to persist data in MVC 5 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, tempdata

I am wanting to develop a MVC 5 project that can provide the same look and feel in terms of styling, header, menu and footer etc, from the calling website.

So for example, the calling website will post a header, menu and footer, or a encrypted key for database lookup, so the MVC project can take this and create a view that will look like the calling website.

This works fine, and I could use `TempData` and `TempData.Keep()` to persist the page styling throughout all the requests.

However, now I want to allow the user on the MVC site to login / authenticate, so that they can see some privileged pages.

The problem I have is I can let the user login, and still persist the styling using `TempData`.  The problem comes when the user session expires, and they click, I lose the styling information.

At the moment I have this controller and action which deals with the login;

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(User user)
{
    TempData["User"] = null;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (user.IsValid(user.Email, user.Password, Request.UserHostAddress))
        {
            string userData = user.Email;
            HttpCookie authCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(user.Email, false);
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
            FormsAuthenticationTicket newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(ticket.Version, ticket.Name, ticket.IssueDate, ticket.Expiration, ticket.IsPersistent, userData);
            authCookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);
            Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

            TempData.Keep("CmsContent");
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "ManageAccount");
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["User"] = user;
            TempData.Keep("CmsContent");
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        user.Message = "Invalid email/password";
        TempData["User"] = user; 
        TempData.Keep("CmsContent");
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

Currently the styling information is being persisted using `TempData.Keep("CmsContent")`, but when the session expires it is lost.

How best can I deal with this sort of issue.

Comment: What is the reason for using tempdata here rather than the httpcontext session?

Comment: Do you mean the HttpContext.Session for the Controller ?

Comment: Yes - as then you wouldn't have to keep calling .Keep as the data would persist for the duration of the user being on the site.

Comment: But what about if there isn't any activity and the session expires ? I assume this would expire too ?

Comment: There is a default expiration of 20mins (I think) but this can be changed. Or you could store the value in a cookie - which you can choose to live for as long as you like (or just until the browser is closed)

Comment: Incidently, TempData uses the session storage by default: http://gregshackles.com/asp-net-mvc-do-you-know-where-your-tempdata-is/